# Pycharm unittest fails to correctly show passed time, which might because I'm using test runners in legacy mode

Tags: pycharm, python-unittest

While running a unittest, a lot of my methods fail to show the correct time passed and instead show "0 ms" while it took multiple seconds. In the terminal it is giving me a warning:

```
Warning: You are using test runners in legacy mode.
That means you have python.tests.enableUniversalTests=false' in registry.
This mode will be dropped in 2021. 
Consider removing this entry from registry and migrating to new test runners
```

I didn't manage to find where I can change this back.

[image: Unittest]

Note: I had problems before where printing outputs were weird, I don't remember how I solved that, but since then I have this problem. I probably have to undo that fix.

Comment: You can open IDE registry with **Help | Find Action -> registry**. Find `python.tests.enableUniversalTests` there and disable it. Not sure if this will resolve the time problem though. Feel free to create a ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Comment: @PavelKarateev Thanks a lot. I don't know how I didn't think of using the Finder, but this indeed solved my problem :).

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [Pavel Karateev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2787185/pavel-karateev):

You can open IDE registry with `Help | Find Action -> registry`. Find `python.tests.enableUniversalTests` there and enable it again. I found it immediately at the top of the registry.